# Dynamically positioning of nubbin failing for corner cases

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).on("mouseover", ".link-item .testDetail", function () {
        let lstPosClass = ["position-nubbin-20", "position-nubbin-40", "position-nubbin-60", "position-nubbin-80"];
        let objElm = $(this).siblings(".slds-popover");
        objElm.css("left", "");
        let lstHtmlCoordinates = objElm.closest("html")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        let lstElmCoordinates = objElm.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        let intleftDiff = lstHtmlCoordinates.width - lstElmCoordinates.left - lstElmCoordinates.width;
        if (Math.sign(intleftDiff) === -1) {
            objElm.css("left", intleftDiff);
            let leftVal = Math.abs(intleftDiff) + 35;
            objElm.attr("data-nubbin-left", leftVal + "px");
            let percent = Math.abs((leftVal / lstElmCoordinates.width) * 100);
            let strNubbinClass = '';
            if (percent > 20 && percent <= 40) {
                strNubbinClass = "position-nubbin-20";
            } else if (percent > 40 && percent <= 60) {
                strNubbinClass = "position-nubbin-40";
            } else if (percent > 60 && percent <= 80) {
                strNubbinClass = "position-nubbin-60";
            } else {
                strNubbinClass = "position-nubbin-80";
            }
            lstPosClass.forEach(function (objClassName) {
                if (objElm.hasClass(objClassName)) {
                    objElm.removeClass(objClassName);
                }
            });
            objElm.addClass(strNubbinClass);
        };
    });
```

**CSS**

```
    .test-page .link-item .slds-popover.position-nubbin-20:before, .slds-popover.position-nubbin-20:after {
        left: 20%;
    }

    .test-page .link-item .slds-popover.position-nubbin-40:before, .slds-popover.position-nubbin-40:after {
        left: 40%;
    }

    .test-page .link-item .slds-popover.position-nubbin-60:before, .slds-popover.position-nubbin-60:after {
        left: 60%;
    }

    .test-page .link-item .slds-popover.position-nubbin-80:before, .slds-popover.position-nubbin-80:after {
        left: 80%;
    }
```

The code above works fine for 2 to 3 pop ups, but fails when there are multiple popups. How can I dynamically set the position of the nubbin [image]

How to resolve this? Any idea? Sorry for hiding the text from popups.

Idea:

I think if I can get hold of the text elements boundary, the I can place the nubbin inbetween them, but I am not sure how to get the boundary of the text element on which the pop up comes.